# This bash scripts given as task for me to solve and replace the keywords as #Expected result given

Tags: bash, scripts

This bash scripts give task for me to solve and replace the keywords  as #Expected result but i run the scripts the error is showing like (cat: demo.txt: No such file or directory )

## Create the file in the name of demo.txt with below content.

```bash
# demo.txt

AAA=demo-73
XXX=
YYY=
ZZZ=demo-11674
```

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# script.sh
function findAndReplace() {
    KEYWORD=$1
    REPLACED_KEYWORD=$2
    FILE=$3
    SearchResults=$(grep -w ${KEYWORD} ${FILE} | wc -l)
    if [ "${SearchResults}" != 0 ]; then
        sed -i 's^'${KEYWORD}'.*^'${KEYWORD}'='${REPLACED_KEYWORD}^'' "${FILE}"
    else
        exit 1
    fi
}

## EXECUTE METHOD
BUILD_NUMBER="123"
# EXCUTION FORMAT FIRST SEARCH KEYWORD, REPLACED_KEYWORD AND TRAGET FILE NAME
findAndReplace "XXX" "demo-${BUILD_NUMBER}" "demo.txt"
findAndReplace "YYY" "yyy-${BUILD_NUMBER}" "demo.txt"
```

### expected result

```
AAA=demo-73
XXX=demo-123
YYY=yyy-123
ZZZ=demo-11674
```

Comment: Stating the obvious(*other issues exist*) ... There is no way the error `cat: demo.txt: No such file or directory` originates from the above script/function .

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way the error:

```
cat: demo.txt: No such file or directory
```

originates from that script as the `cat` command is not used in the script  ... I would imagine an error from `grep` with:

```
grep: demo.txt: No such file or directory
```

is possible if the file `demo.txt` is not in the same directory from where you run that script i.e. you need to either first `cd` to the directory containing the `demo.txt` file and then run your script from there or you need to set the full path to the `demo.txt` file in your function's argument.

**Unless,** you are also creating and populating the `demo.txt` using a [here document](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) syntax with `cat`(*which can result in a `cat: demo.txt: No such file or directory` error if not used right*) ... The right way for that would look like this:

```bash
cat << EOF > demo.txt
AAA=demo-73
XXX=
YYY=
ZZZ=demo-11674
EOF
```

Otherwise, you have put excellent effort in writing the script and it should work as expected ... With minor remarks:

- `grep` by itself can count lines if given the option `-c` like so:

  ```
  SearchResults=$(grep -c "${KEYWORD}" "${FILE}")
  ```
- Double quote your variables when using them in a command to prevent globbing and word splitting.

So your script will look something like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# script.sh
function findAndReplace() {
    KEYWORD=$1
    REPLACED_KEYWORD=$2
    FILE=$3
    SearchResults=$(grep -c "${KEYWORD}" "${FILE}")
    if [ "${SearchResults}" != 0 ]; then
        sed -i 's^'"${KEYWORD}"'.*^'"${KEYWORD}"'='"${REPLACED_KEYWORD}"^'' "${FILE}"
    else
        exit 1
    fi
}


## EXECUTE METHOD
BUILD_NUMBER="123"
# EXCUTION FORMAT FIRST SEARCH KEYWORD, REPLACED_KEYWORD AND TRAGET FILE NAME
findAndReplace "XXX" "demo-${BUILD_NUMBER}" "demo.txt"
findAndReplace "YYY" "yyy-${BUILD_NUMBER}" "demo.txt"
```

- Also refrain from using all-caps variable names as the shells reserved variable names are also all-caps to avoid conflicts.
- It is worth mentioning as well (*special thanks to [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422665/this-bash-scripts-given-as-task-for-me-to-solve-and-replace-the-keywords-as-exp#comment2476391_1422680)*) that you don't actually need to count the matching lines if your aim is just to verify that a match exists(*which is apparently the case given the `if [ "${SearchResults}" != 0 ]; then` statement*) ... You can instead rely on `grep`s exit status with the `-q` option which will not write anything to standard output and will exit immediately with zero(*i.e. success*) status if any match is found, even if an error was detected i.e. `grep -q --` ... The `--` will indicate the end of `grep`s options and prevent errors in case the following pattern starts with a dash(*`-`*)... So that if statement would look like so:

  ```
  if grep -q -- "${KEYWORD}" "${FILE}"; then
  ```
- Also `sed` will try to match and substitute from the given file e.g. `demo.txt` whether it actually contains the search pattern or not ... It will only substitute if the pattern is matched and skip otherwise ... It will also exit with a zero(*success*) whether a match was found and substituted or not ... The only thing that might be of concern in this `sed` processing the file with the `-i` option is that it will modify its timestamp ... If that is not a concern the your script can be as simple(*can be simplified more if positional parameters `$1`, `$2` and `$3` are to be used directly in the `sed` command*) as:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function findAndReplace() {
    KEYWORD=$1
    REPLACED_KEYWORD=$2
    FILE=$3
    sed -i 's^'"${KEYWORD}"'.*^'"${KEYWORD}"'='"${REPLACED_KEYWORD}"^'' "${FILE}"
}

## EXECUTE METHOD
BUILD_NUMBER="123"
# EXCUTION FORMAT FIRST SEARCH KEYWORD, REPLACED_KEYWORD AND TRAGET FILE NAME
findAndReplace "XXX" "demo-${BUILD_NUMBER}" "demo.txt"
findAndReplace "YYY" "yyy-${BUILD_NUMBER}" "demo.txt"
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that you don't need to count matching lines in order to test whether a file contains a keyword - a test based on the grep command's *exit status* is better practice (one reason being efficiency - it exits on the first match): `if grep -q -- "${KEYWORD}" "${FILE}"; then`. Of course you don't really need the check at all unless you care about `sed -i` modifying `${FILE}`'s timestamp in the case when it doesn't modify its contents.

Comment: @steeldriver It is worth mentioning indeed and I totally missed it ... Kindly, have a look and let me know if I skipped something ... Appreciate your feedback :-)